How to clean all junk files from ubuntu
There is something really bad in Debian based systems and that is you can't easily remove junks like removed apps, apps cache, browser cache and other junks.
The most used command to clean junk is : sudo apt clean
But that is not really helpful and does not clean all junks.
Is there anyone with a simple solution like a script that goes and remove junk files?

Please clearly define "junk files" (i.e. which files) and include this in your question - especially the undefined "other junks".

-1: The question grossly misleads about the purpose and actions of apt's clean function. It has never been intended to "clean all junks." For the past 20+ years, it has done something quite different. See man apt-get for the clear description of what clean really does.

This question handles how to remove old kernel versions.

How to clean out what you explicitly have stated: (I'm not sure what you mean by "App cache" and "Other junk".)
Data from removed .deb packages
Run this to simulate:
sudo apt purge --dry-run ?config-files

Remove the --dry-run option to actually fire the purge command.
Snapshots from removed snap packages
Run this to see saved snapshots:
snap saved

Run this to remove a particular snapshot
sudo snap forget #

Where # is the number of the snapshot.
See here for more info.
Clear browser cache
This is done from your chosen webbrowser, typically by going to:

"Settings" -> "Privacy" -> "Clear Data" (Or something similar)

